# Selenium IDE - verifyText [error] Actual value '' did not match <acct name>

Tags: selenium-ide

1st time post. I'm running a Selenium IDE script in which populated account information is supposed to be verified. I'm using verifyText to do this however I'm getting the error that the actual did not match the value I have set. In this case, I'm hardcoding the value because I know what to expect and I'm copying the value straight from the site. I've attempted to copy the values into a text editor to see if there are any hidden characters but haven't found any. There are 5 fields on the page this happening with.
Here is the IDE script for the rows and the logs. I've exchanged the actual client info with variables

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=NAME_ON_ACCOUNT</td>
    <td><AcctName></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=ADDRESS_1</td>
    <td><AcctAddress></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=CITY_PROVINCE</td>
    <td><AcctCity></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=ZIP</td>
    <td><AcctZip></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=PHONE</td>
    <td><AcctPhone></td>
</tr>
```

and here are the logs

```
[info] Executing: |verifyText | id=NAME_ON_ACCOUNT | <AcctName> |
[error] Actual value '' did not match '<AcctName>'
[info] Executing: |verifyText | id=ADDRESS_1 | <AcctAddress> |
[error] Actual value '' did not match '<AcctAddress>'
[info] Executing: |verifyText | id=CITY_PROVINCE | <AcctCity> |
[error] Actual value '' did not match '<AcctCity>'
[info] Executing: |verifyText | id=ZIP | <AcctZip> |
[error] Actual value '' did not match '<AcctZip>'
[info] Executing: |verifyText | id=PHONE | <AcctPhone> |
[error] Actual value '' did not match '<AcctPhone>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the text from an input field, but you can store its "value" attribute, then check that this value equals a certain text. For example:

```
storeAttribute | id=NAME_ON_ACCOUNT@value | nameValue
verifyEquals | ${nameValue} | <AcctName>
```

Comment: thanks. going at it from a "value" perspective fixed my issue.